# Laravel Dependency Injection with inheritance

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

Let's say I have the following case:

```
<?php

abstract class Service {

    protected $config;

    public function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }
}

class ClientService extends Service {

}

class ProductService extends Service {

}
```

Is it possible to register in my service provider the dependency injection for the Abstract parent class of my services ?

I have an API which is generated dynamically from a specification, and each one of those classes must extend the `abstract Service` so it can inherit for basic functionalities.

How can I Inject dependencies in my abstract service when I instantiate a child Service ?

---

**EDIT:** This question was specifically asked for Abstract class injection, without the possibility to bind the child classes which are generated automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you have to manually pass the `config` object every time you instantiate from `Service` class or a child class.

So when you want to directly instantiate a child service, you could use something like, `$cs = new ClientService(new Config());`

However, you can use the real advantage of DI (since you are using Laravel), by type hinting the class name in the constructor like below.

```
public function __construct(\Config $config)
```

This way, if you do not pass a parameter when instantiating, it would by default create an object of the type-hinted class and inject it. So you could then use it like.

`$cs = new ClientService();`

This would inject a Laravel `Config` instance into the `ClientService` object.

Comment: Ok so I have no real way of injecting some more specific code in the abstract class ? I have to stick with automatic DI from laravel in this precise case ?

Comment: Yes, but the good thing is, if you are using this class elsewhere, you have the option to manually pass whatever `config` instance that you may have. You can always do  `ClientService(new SomeOtherConfig());`

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible things you could do here. First, if `$config` is a class, then you can type hint it in the abstract class:

```
abstract class Service {

    protected $config;

    public function __construct(ClassName $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }
}
```

Then every time the child classes get resolved via injection or by calling `App::make('ClientService')`, the config class will be injected.

If the config is not a class and can't be type hinted, you will have to bind the child classes into the container individually:

```
App::bind('ClientService', function () {
    // Get $config from somewhere first

    return new ClientService($config);
});

App::bind('ProductService', function () {
    // Get $config from somewhere first

    return new ProductService($config);
});
```

Then you will be able to call `App::make('ClientService')` or have it resolved via DI.

Comment: Indeed I thought about this but I'd like to avoid because Service classes are generated from a spec with a cron task, so (it shouldn't happen, but who knows) some class could be added and I'd have to update my service provider manually

Comment: Surely that still wouldn't stop the first option working?

Comment: of course, I think that's what I'll be doing, I'll pick the other answer as it answered my case prior to yours